# COMException (0x80040154): Class not registered when using AxAcroPDFLib

Tags: c#, winforms, comexception, interopservices

I am getting following error when using AxAcroPDF

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

The line which throws error is

```
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.axAcroPDF1)).EndInit();
```

If anyone knows the solution please help

Comment: There are two questions: 1.Did you install / register the COM component on the Windows 7 x64 machine? 2.What the target platform of your application, I think you should set the platform to x86, please do not set it as "Any CPU"? Please register the COM first and then run to test the application, please refer to the document: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/146219/ and Explanation of Regsvr32 usage and error messages

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that your ActiveX control is not registered.

In that case, you would need to call RegSvr32 on the *.ocx or *.dll file (I don't know which for AxAcroPDF).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67167/axacropdf-vista64-class-not-registered-error) is very similar to yours. They found that they weren't registered properly because it was a 64 bit target system. Make sure you use the right version of regsvr32 for the control. One is for 32 bit and one is for 64 bit.

Answer (score 4):

I had already installed the correct version of the DLL file (32bit dll on 32bit Windows XP) and put it as my Project References when I was having this problem.

I had solved this problem by just installing the Adobe Reader software which is required by the AxAcroPDFLib.dll file.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this same error and in my case I was able to resolve this error by performing following steps.

In Visual Studio Go to build -> options->projects and solutions-> web projects
In this tab un-check the option of use the 64 bit version of IIS express for websites and projects.

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar error they are gone after I am install Adobe Reader on my PC.